# Android thread get parameters

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I'm trying to get some information from a thread and i dont know how.
I never used threads and my question is about that.

I have one activity what uses a webservice with one thread. After this i want to do some action if the result is true and do other if the result is false.

I cant modify local or global variables in the thread so i dont know how to do. I don't want to throw the intent in the thread.

Is there any way to return this result? thanks

This is my activity code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

//Constantes para la invocacion del web service
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://webservice.proyecto";
private static String URL="http://192.168.1.34:8080/BDManejador/services/conexion?wsdl";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "nuevo_usuario";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://ws.webapp.ejemplo/nuevo_usuario";  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}

public void goMainMenu (View v) {

    final EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user);
    final EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    EditText repeat_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rpass);

    // COMPROBAR EMAIL VALIDO
    if((email.getText().toString().length() == 0) || (!email.getText().toString().contains("@")) ||(!email.getText().toString().contains("."))) {
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DIRECCIÓN DE CORREO ELECTRÓNICO NO VÁLIDA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else {

        // COMPROBAR CONTRASEÑA REPETIDA IGUAL
        if((password.getText().toString().compareTo(repeat_password.getText().toString()) == 0) && (password.getText().toString().length()!=0)) {

            // USAMOS EL WEBSERVICE

            Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  try {
                     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
                     request.addProperty("email", email.getText().toString());
                     request.addProperty("pass", password.getText().toString());

                     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                     HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                     final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                     final boolean str = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());
                     if (str) {
                         Log.v("MYAPP",  "INSERTADO");
                     }
                     else
                         Log.v("MYAPP",  "NO INSERTADO");
                  } 
                 catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                }
            };
            networkThread.start();

            //ESPERAR QUE TERMINE LA OPERACION
            try {
                networkThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               

            //LANZAR LA NUEVA ACTIVIDAD
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else {
            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LAS CONTRASEÑAS DEBEN SER IGUALES", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}

}
```

So I want to throw my intent when variable boolean `str` is true.

Someone can help?

Comment: use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html from android or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html from standard Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI cannot be manipulated on some other non-UI threads.

I think you should go with `AsyncTask` interface.

See this reference :

[Painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

For such long and time consuming background tasks `AsyncTask` is a best choice. By which you can easily execute things in background and on completion of job you can update UI from the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: u can manupulate ui components from different thread if you use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: @anfy2002us I know but that is not preferable here to call that from the normal running thread. So it is good to go with AsyndTask in this case.

Comment: thanks both!!
so the UIthread start running when "father" thread is done?

Comment: @user1751840 after the completion of  `doInBackground` job `onPostExecute` method will call by `AsyncTask` itself. We dont need to handle manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a handler in your thread.

Pass a new handler when you create a thread.

Inside the thread, use handler.post(new Runnable () { public void run(){ aMethod(); } });

Then, implement aMethod outside the thread (in your activity class) to do whatever you want to do.